# ClassCastException: app crashes when using DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, classcastexception

I have a `RecyclerView` in my `MainActivity.java`. In each RecyclerView row, I have a button, and when it's pressed, it supposed to open a customized fragment dialog with RecyclerView list in it (it's a multi-choice dialog).

In my `SecondActivity.java`, which is my other activity, I also have the same button which is supposed to do the same thing (this is why I need the modal to be the fragment dialog). In my `SecondActivity.java`, there is no RecyclerView, it's just a single post (detail page).

**My problem:**

When I click on the button for the popup on `SecondActivity.java`, it opens the dialog fragment popup normally. When I do the same for any individual row in my RecyclerView (which is in `MainActivity.java`), I get a `ClassCastException` error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.appname.MainActivity cannot be cast to interfaces.DialogCommunicator$Communicator
```

**My code:**

**SecondActivity.java**

```
//*****************//
// THIS CODE WORKS //
//*****************//

// This code will run when the button is clicked.
// postOptions is a string array of menu items.
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putStringArray("displaymenu", postOptions);
mDialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();
mDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
mDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "title");
```

**PostsListAdapter.java**

```
//***************************//
// THIS CODE CRASHES THE APP //
//***************************//

// This code is planted in onClick method listener in onBindViewHolder
// for the button that's supposed to open the fragment dialog.
FragmentManager fm = ((MainActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
String[] items = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.post_options);
CustomDialogFragment customDialogFragment = CustomDialogFragment.newInstance(items);
customDialogFragment.show(fm, "title");
```

**CustomDialogFragment.java**

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public CustomDialogFragment() {
        // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
        // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
        // Use `newInstance` instead as shown below
    }

    public static CustomDialogFragment newInstance(String[] items) {
        CustomDialogFragment customDialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray("displaymenu", items);
        customDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        return customDialogFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_multiselect_dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String[] items = args.getStringArray("displaymenu");
        List<String> itemsList = Arrays.asList(items);

        // THIS LINE CRASHES ON POSTSLISTADAPTER!!!
        MultiDialogAdapter adapter = new MultiDialogAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.items_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        getDialog().setTitle(null);
    }

}
```

**MultiDialogAdapter.java**

```
public class MultiDialogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MultiDialogViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private CustomFonts mCustomFont;
    private DialogCommunicator.Communicator mCommunicator;

    public MultiDialogAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mItems = items;
        this.mCustomFont = new CustomFonts(context);

        try {
            mCommunicator = (DialogCommunicator.Communicator) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // THIS IS WHERE THE CLASSCASTEXCEPTION HAPPENS!
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MultiDialogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_multiselect_dialog_row, parent, false);
        return new MultiDialogViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MultiDialogViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String item = mItems.get(position);
        holder.getItemTextView().setText(item);
        holder.getItemTextView().setTypeface(mCustomFont.getPrimaryFontMedium());
        holder.getItemTextView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCommunicator.onDialogButtonResponse(item);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

}

class MultiDialogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mItemTextView;

    public MultiDialogViewHolder(View rootView) {
        super(rootView);
        mItemTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_view);
    }

    public TextView getItemTextView() {
        return mItemTextView;
    }

}
```

**DialogCommunicator.java**

```
public class DialogCommunicator {

    public interface Communicator {
        public void onDialogButtonResponse(String responseMessage);
    }

}
```

**Crash log:**

```
10-06 14:35:12.353 21683-21683/com.example.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.appname, PID: 21683
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.appname.MainActivity@e06db1e
    at adapters.MultiDialogAdapter.<init>(MultiDialogAdapter.java:40)
    at fragments.CustomDialogFragment.onViewCreated(CustomDialogFragment.java:60)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1430)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I have that interface which is implemented in `PostsListAdapter.java` and `SecondActivity.java`. This is a callback method so I can respond to each individual action and know what item is clicked inside the fragment dialog popup.

So, I have built the dialog fragment correctly because it works in a normal activity outside of a list, but for each row in a RecyclerView list, that dialog fragment crashes the app because of the `ClassCastException`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crash is very explicit:

> `MainActivity` cannot be cast to `DialogCommunicator$Communicator`

According to what you've posted, you have not implemented this interface in `MainActivity`. You said:

> I have that interface which is implemented in `PostsListAdapter.java` and `SecondActivity.java`.

Chances are extremely good that you should remove the `implements DialogCommunicator.Communicator` line from `PostsListAdapter` and add it to `MainActivity` instead (and move the actual implementation as well, of course).

The nitty-gritty cause is this line:

```
MultiDialogAdapter adapter = new MultiDialogAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
```

You're passing `getActivity()` as the `Context` argument to your adapter's constructor. This would be fine, except that your dialog's constructor then casts this `Context` instance to your interface. So every `Activity` that this dialog could be shown in must implement your interface.

Comment: YES! Removing the `implements DialogCommunicator.Communicator` from `PostsListAdapter.java` and adding it in `MainActivity.java` was the problem. @Anonymous was also right, I accidentally put `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`, that part slipped accidentally. It was crashing because it was trying to use the interface based on `MainActivity` context which didn't implement it. 4 weeks of agony with a stupid bug, is finally over. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing context as a object you can get the construtor in the onCreateViewHolder using `parent.getContext().`

Also in the onBindViewholder you forgot to typecast viewholder.Add

```
MultiDialogViewHolder viewholder=(MultiDialogViewHolder)holder;
```

Then access  `viewholder.getItemTextView().setText(item);`

Also before typcasting the context in adapter your dialog fragment should implement `DialogCommunicator`.Add implementaion of `DialogCommunicator` in the dialog fragment

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogCommunicator {

 //override the method
}
```

**EDIT**:

Also main problem the error occuring is because of the context.
Here pass         `MultiDialogAdapter adapter=new MultiDialogAdapter(getContext(), itemsList)` .

If your are passing getActivity() to the adapter then your corresponding activity has to implement the interface `DialogCommunicator` and the callback comes to activity instead of `CustomDialogFragment`.

So pass `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()` because CustomDialogFragment is implementing the interface and not the activity.

Comment: I moved try/catch block of Communicator interface from constructor to `onCreateViewHolder` like you said, it still crashes. I don't see the point of typecasting the same viewholder if it's the same type to begin with, but it still crashes. Also implemented the interface in CustomDialogFragment, still crashes.

Comment: Can you post log?previously you had not implemented that DialogFragment so you were getting error

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: update the code of CustomDialogFragment also with implementing the listsner class

Comment: It's the same thing. Also, if I move the try/catch code into `onCreateViewHolder` and replace `context` with `parent.getContext()`, it crashes in `SecondActivity.java` too